# Django asymettrical self through relationship query

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following - simplified - models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='Following', symmetrical=False)

class Following(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

The status is 0 for pending, 1 for following
Let user be a User. I would like to get all the followed users of user

I can do

```
user.following.all()
```

to get all the users user is following (pending relationships OR really follow)

or

```
Following.objects.filter(from_user=user, status=1)
```

to get all the Following objects with User user and real friendship

But how can I get all the User objects for user and status=1 ?
I can't seem to find a way

Thank you !

Comment: is the from_user ForeignKey to UserProfile or to User?

Comment: well actually this is a very simplified version of my models and I forgot to change UserProfile to User, thanks, editing

Comment: Did you perchance slapped on the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to the user model?

Comment: I am using the module but here I was only copy and pasting, I am trying to make this work with this simplified version first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
user.following.filter(to_user__status=1)
```

the `user.following` is still querying on `User`, thus you need to span relation w/ `__` to `Follow` here.

The two fields here, `from_user` and `to_user`, are both `ForeignKey` pointing to `User` model. Thus for an `User()` instance `u`:

- `u.following` searches for the `User()`s who have relationship w/ `u` through the intermediate table, the `Follow`. The key here is that `u.following` picks the first `ForeignKey` in the `Follow` that points to the `User`, as the reference to `u` itself. Thus for your version of `Follow`, `u.following.filter(to_user__status=1)` filters on the `Follow` items having `from_user` equals to `u` and `to_user` w/ `status` equals to `1`. The lookup is typical [following relationship backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)
- `u.from_user` searches the intermediate table for those having `from_user` equals to `u`
- `u.to_user` searches the intermediate table for those having `to_user` equals to `u`

Also, you could filter on the `ForeignKey` directly, w/ remembering that the `from_user` and `to_user` are both ref the `Follow`:

```
User.objects.filter(to_user__from_user=user, to_user__status=1) # user as from_user
User.objects.filter(from_user__to_user=user, from_user__status=1) # user as to_user
User.objects.filter(following=user) # those who are followed by `to_user` user
```

Comment: I had tried that but had the following error:
`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are: following, id`

Comment: @noe Please post the whole error msg, normally it lists the available choices.

Comment: Looks like you have the Manager of User there.

Comment: Sorry i copied the wrong line, here is the right one:
`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are: following, from_user, id, to_user, user`
when I do user.following.filter(status=1) ...

Comment: This seems to be working but can you explain the `to_user__status` part? I don't understand how this works..
`user.following` is a ManyRelatedManager which, as you said, is querying on User. So `user.following` is to find User objects user is following, and how does `to_user` come in handy?
What would `user.following.filter(from_user__status=1)` do? The result of this query is not very logical, it seems to me.
Thanks again, once I understand I will validate :)

Comment: @noe I've enrich the answer, hope it helps =)

Comment: @okm Thanks a lot !
So how should I do this if in my Following model I had put from_user in second position and not first?

Comment: @noe switch all appearances of `from_user` and `to_user` literally would works then.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that

```
user.following.filter(to_user__status=1)
```

does the trick. Can someone explain to me why, and how this works?
`user.following` is a ManyRelatedManager which is querying on User. What would `user.following.filter(from_user__status=1)` do? Can't to guess what it returns...
Thanks again !