# Django: How to add counts of non-related object?

Tags: sql, django, count, relation

I have two indirectly related tables - `Posts` and `Follower_to_followee`

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Author', help_text="Author")

    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, help_text="Post Title")

    post_content = models.TextField (help_text="Post Content")

class Follower_to_followee(models.Model):

    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_followers', null=True, blank=True, help_text="Follower")

    followee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_followees', null=True, blank=True, help_text="Followee")
```

The folowee is indirectly related to post auth_user (post author) in posts. It is, though, directly related to Django user table and user table is directly related to post table.

How can I select all followees for a specific follower and include post counts for each followee in the result of the query without involving the user table? Actually, at this point I am not even clear how to do that involving the user table. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write query generating single SQL, try something like

```
qs = User.objects.filter(user_followees__follower=specific_follower).annotate(
         post_count=models.Count('post'))
for u in qs:
    print u, u.post_count
```

Check the second part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293460/165603 (things work similarly except the extra M2M manager)

When being used inside `User.objects.filter`, both `user_followees__follower=foo` and `user_followers__followee=foo` would cause joining of the table of the `Follower_to_followee` model and a `where` condition checking for `follower=foo` or `followee=foo`
 (Note that `user_followees__followee=foo` or `user_followerers__follower=foo` works differently from above, Django ORM simplifies them smartly and would generate something like `User.objects.filter(pk=foo.pk)`).

Comment: Thanks you all so much! I went with the query generating single SQL and it worked perfectly! Now I can display a list of followees for a specific follower and output post count for each followee next to the followee name...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but here is a simple solution.  Note that this could be written more succinctly, but I broke it up so you can see each step.

> How can I select all followees for a specific follower?

```
# First grab all the follower_to_followee entries for a given 
# follower called: the_follower
follows = Follower_to_followee.objects.filter(follower=the_follower)

followee_counts = []

# Next, let's iterate through those objects and pick out 
# the followees and their posts
for follow in follows:
    followee = follow.followee

    # post for each followee
    followee_posts = Post.objects.filter(auth_user=followee).count()

    # Count number of posts in the queryset
    count = followee_posts.count()

    # Add followee/post_counts to our list of followee_counts
    followee_counts.append((followee, count))

# followee_counts is now a list of followee/post_count tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

For get post counts you can use this:

```
#get follower
follower = User.objects.get(username='username_of_fallower')
#get all followees for a specific follower
for element in Follower_to_followee.objects.filter(follower=follower):
    element.followee.post_set.all().count()
```

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
def view_name(request):
    followers = Follower_to_followee.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    .......
```

**html**

```
{{user}}<br/>

My followers:<br/>    
{% follower in followers %}
    <p>{{follower}} - {{follower.user.follower_to_followee_set.count}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```